# Why would the output image from this code be darker than the original?

Tags: c#, image, .net-4.0, system.drawing

I'm a newbie to working with images in NET. My goal is to add text and an icon to the starting image, then save the output.

The result comes out a bit darker.  Starting with a solid image (png-24) #788eb3 comes out #6d84ab.  Tested to insure background/transparency is not the issue.

I removed everything except the code to get the image, then save it, and the result is still darker.  What direction should I go to make this work better?

```
System.Drawing.Image img = Bitmap.FromFile(@"c:\\oldfile.png", true);
img.Save(@"c:\\newfile.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

Comment: Alpha channel + background?  Have you tried displaying the image over a white background?

Comment: Is maybe the second argument (UseEmbeddedColorManagement) manipulating some of the colors when you create the image by using Bitmap.FromFile()?

Comment: background and colorManagement arg are not it. As next test, I created a Graphics object from the Image, created a custom brush with #788eb3, used it to add text, and the text also renders as #6d84ab. Time to delve into why Save modifies the color, I guess..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real issue turned out to be the browser!  IE7 and IE8 render #788eb3 in a png differently than the same color as a css background color.  IE9, Chrome and Firefox all look good.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have the color correction turned on. Try passing false instead of true to Bitmap.FromFile.

Comment: unfortunately this makes no difference either way.  I have access to the original Photoshop file, so may be able to add color profile to that.

Comment: @heathen Have you tried a different format such as bmp, gif, tiff, or jpeg and see if they have the same effect? It may be getting lost in translation so to speak. Sort of like decoding an encoded video stream then re-encoding has a loss of quality?